# Is it correct to escape "&", ">" and "<" with &#38;, &#62; and &#60; in XML?

Tags: xml, encode, entities

Will something "break" if I use numeric entities instead of the usual recommended  alpha entities for reserved chars in XML?

This is part of a rather complex app that allows users to enter bibliographic metadata via XML, CSV or web-based forms.
This data can then be extracted in XML (using the [ONIX](http://www.editeur.org/8/ONIX/) standard) with user-chosen encodings: utf-8, win-1252, etc.

The original programmers (long gone now...) decided to use numeric entities for all chars that cannot be represented in the chosen encoding.
XML-reserved chars are considered as non-representable under any encoding. They are given the same treatment and are encoded using numeric entities.

Some users have complained about &, <, >, etc. being encoded as &#38, etc. instead of using the usual alpha codes and I'd like to know if these complaints have any substance.

If I can avoid digging through the legacy code to change this behaviour, it would save me a lot of resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to escape using numeric character references.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) (emphasis mine):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either ***numeric
>   character references*** or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`"
>   respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the
>   string "`&gt;`", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string "`]]>`"
>   in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.

You could also use a hex entity reference...

`&amp;` = `&#38;` = `&#x26;`

`&lt;` = `&#60;` = `&#x3C;`

`&gt;` = `&#62;` = `&#x3E;`